# Unlock Screen with ADB Android 4.2

Tags: lock-screens, adb, 4.2-jelly-bean

Previously with Android 4.1, doing something like:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82  
#(KEYCODE_MENU)
```

would unlock the screen at first boot and would then allow further commands to launch applications and have them displayed on the screen, etc.

With 4.2, within 10s of boot, the lockscreen dims to black. Issuing the same ADB command no longer works and the screen remains blank.

If I manually press the menu key, this brings the screen back on, and I can then issue the keyevent to unlock the screen.

Any ideas how I can bring the display back up from ADB and unlock the screen from there?

Thanks

Comment: There is a list of keyevents [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/2943276) and [here](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html), if anyone needs it for reference...

Answer (score 4):

If you are on 4.2.2, you might want to read e.g. [ADB Whitelist As of the Android 4.2.2](https://plus.google.com/+CyanogenMod/posts/M2pVM7Y6MTq): Starting with this Android version, "remote devices" (i.e. those you run ADB commands *from*) must be authorized by the Android device (i.e. the one those commands are runnin *on*) -- so your Android device can tell "trusted callers" from "malicious attackers". You can also find this in detail on [this article on AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/12/new-android-4-2-2-feature-usb-debug-whitelist-prevents-adb-savvy-thieves-from-stealing-your-data-in-some-situations/):

> The way it works is pretty simple - when you connect your PC to your Android device via USB, Android gets your PC's RSA key (an identifier token). In Android 4.2.2, when you have USB debugging enabled, this now causes a prompt to appear on connection, seen below.

[image: Authorization Prompt]
<sup>(image source: [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/12/new-android-4-2-2-feature-usb-debug-whitelist-prevents-adb-savvy-thieves-from-stealing-your-data-in-some-situations/))</sup>

<sup>Update from the comments below:</sup>

Additionally, as *Shurane* pointed out, behavior of `adb keyevent` seems to have changed with Android 4.2.2: while before `adb keyevent 26` was a dedicated "screen-off", and `adb shell input keyevent 82` a dedicated "screen-on" switch, now `adb keyevent 26` is a *toggle* which turns the screen off (when it's on) and on (when it's off), as noted by *Pepelac*.

Comment: Even after `adb whitelisting`, sending a keyevent in 4.2.2 doesn't work the same way.

Comment: Your comment suggests it works in a different way then. Do you mind to elaborate a little more? Might even be worth a separate answer.

Comment: Well, `adb shell input keyevent 26` turns the screen off and `adb shell input keyevent 82` turns the screen back on, right? But for 4.2.2, only `keyevent 26` seems to work. `keyevent 82` doesn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: I see. Not having a 4.2+ device, I cannot check myself -- but maybe somebody else has some hints on that.

Comment: @Shurane `adb shell input keyevent 26` turns it off/on

Comment: @Pepelac that should probably be the answer to the question then.

Comment: I integrated that with my answer. Thanks, @Pepelac!

Comment: keyevent 82 is the menu button. keyevent 26 is power button. As Shurane said, it's on/off.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in 4.4.x and/or other systems you have to send an <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the command or else you have to wait x sec/min.

So do it like:

```
adb shell

@shell: input keyevent 26

@shell: 

@shell: exit
```

This will work in any case, I think.

Comment: worked for me on Android 4.1.1 (screen refuses to turn on w power button)

Answer (score 0):

Set the device in "no lock" mode in security settings (lock settings in some android versions) so that after reboot the OS goes straight to the home screen.

You can then send any key event, best an unrecognised one so it's not handled by the default handler, to wake up the screen.

EDIT: This works fine on 4.1. I checked on 4.4 and events other than 26 do not work when the screen is off. This is I guess because there is another separate device now defined for the power button and the other ones might be inactive. So you have to check if the screen is off (dumpsys power, look for mScreenOn) and if off send 26. You have to do the check to prevent switching it off while it's on. This will work on all Android versions.